# Calendar drop down bug

Tags: php, date, datepicker

This should be quite simple but I can`t fix it :/

I am using a component that displays a list of months, the upcoming 12 to be exact. However, the year does not change to 2012 when past December.

See here:
http://protekco.com/index.php/en/reservation.html

And the code that calls it:

```
        echo AHtml::getMonthsSelect('imonth', (int) $month, $year, $currentMonth, $currentYear, $config->calendarDeepMonth, 'onchange="Calendars.monthNavigation(this.value)"'); ?>
```

The $currentYear is the actual year variable that is presented on the site. I basically need someway to add +1 if we are past the end of the year. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: here is the months array:

```
 function getMonthsSelect($name, $selectedMonth, $selectedYear, $month, $year, $deep, $attribs = '')
{
    $months = array(1 => JText::_('January') , 2 => JText::_('February') , 3 => JText::_('March') , 4 => JText::_('April') , 5 => JText::_('May') , 6 => JText::_('June') , 7 => JText::_('July') , 8 => JText::_('August') , 9 => JText::_('September') , 10 => JText::_('October') , 11 => JText::_('November') , 12 => JText::_('December'));

    $stop = $month + $deep;
    for ($i = $month; $i < $stop; $i ++)
        $arr[] = JHTML::_('select.option', ($key = (! ($k = $i % 12) ? 12 : $k)) . ',' . ($y = (floor(($i - $month) / 12) + $year)), ($months[$key] . '/' . $y));

    return JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $arr, $name, $attribs, 'value', 'text', $selectedMonth . ',' . $selectedYear);
}
```

Edit 3: Final solution:

```
function getMonthsSelect($name, $selectedMonth, $selectedYear, $month, $year, $deep, $attribs = '')
{
    $months = array(1 => JText::_('January') , 2 => JText::_('February') , 3 => JText::_('March') , 4 => JText::_('April') , 5 => JText::_('May') , 6 => JText::_('June') , 7 => JText::_('July') , 8 => JText::_('August') , 9 => JText::_('September') , 10 => JText::_('October') , 11 => JText::_('November') , 12 => JText::_('December'));

    $stop = $month + $deep;
    $wheremonth = 12 - $month;
    for ($i = $month; $i < $stop; $i ++, $wheremonth--)

    if ($wheremonth >= 0) {
        $arr[] = JHTML::_('select.option', ($key = (! ($k = $i % 12) ? 12 : $k)) . ',' . ($y = (floor(($i - $month) / 12) + $year)), ($months[$key] . '/' . $y));
        }
        else {            $arr[] = JHTML::_('select.option', ($key = (! ($k = $i % 12) ? 12 : $k)) . ',' . ($y = (floor(($i - $month) / 12) + $year+1)), ($months[$key] . '/' . $y));
        }
    return JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $arr, $name, $attribs, 'value', 'text', $selectedMonth . ',' . $selectedYear);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how the inputs are working here, but you have next month and previous month. You can implement a counter variable that adds when you hit next and subtracts when you hit previous. So something like:

```
$i = 1;

function datetracker() {

if($nextbtnclicked = true) {
     $i++;
} elseif($prevbtnclicked = true) {
     $i--;
}

if($i == 13) {
     $i = 1;
     $currentYear += 1;
}
}
```

I'm just using sample variables, but you can implement the counter in the Javascript and do the login in JS.

EDIT: That code actually looks right. Don't know why it's not working, but try something like this.

```
function getMonthsSelect($name, $selectedMonth, $selectedYear, $month, $year, $deep, $attribs = '') 
{ 
    $months = array(1 => JText::_('January') , 2 => JText::_('February') , 3 => JText::_('March') , 4 => JText::_('April') , 5 => JText::_('May') , 6 => JText::_('June') , 7 => JText::_('July') , 8 => JText::_('August') , 9 => JText::_('September') , 10 => JText::_('October') , 11 => JText::_('November') , 12 => JText::_('December')); 

    $stop = $month + $deep;
    $newyear = false;
    for ($i = $month; $i < $stop; $i ++) {

        if($newyear) {
        $arr[] = JHTML::_('select.option', ($key = (! ($k = $i % 12) ? 12 : $k)) . ',' . ($y = (floor(($i - $month) / 12) + $year + 1)), ($months[$key] . '/' . $y));
         $newyear = false;
        } else {
        $arr[] = JHTML::_('select.option', ($key = (! ($k = $i % 12) ? 12 : $k)) . ',' . ($y = (floor(($i - $month) / 12) + $year)), ($months[$key] . '/' . $y));

        }
     if($i == 12) { $newyear = true; }
     }

    return JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $arr, $name, $attribs, 'value', 'text', $selectedMonth . ',' . $selectedYear); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; there are already variables such as Currentmonth, and NextYear etc. They work for the large bottom calendar. When clicking on the Next Month link at the bottom of the calendar, it adds +1 to the current month value, until it reaches 12. Then it adds a +1 value to current year and resets currentmonth to 1 etc. I`m just not sure how to get that done pre-loading on the dropdown select box!

Comment: Well then you have to track if you already used a certain month. Maybe build an array of the $month as you loop through to add the months. Each time it loops you check the array, and if the $month exists you set $currentYear + 1.

Comment: that sounds like a perfect solution. I am really not familiar with building arrays however, if you could drop a line of code or two it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The php.net manual probably does a better job of explaining: http://php.net/array and to check if a value is in an array: http://php.net/in_array

Comment: I`ve been reading on it but really not sure how to actually implement that, my drop down only contains one line that already seems to call an array, as it understands when to switch back to January. I`m just not sure where it comes from or how I can make it understand that at the same time it switches to Jan, then add +1 to currentYear

Comment: Found it actually, would you be so kind as to indicate how to add the +1 to the year? I modified my original question. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: That`s the reason I`m on here, I don`t know how. The function is presented as is. I don`t think it needs much of a modification, but I don`t know what to do about it, most of it is chinese to me!

Comment: It actually looks right to me. I tried to do some modifications. Might not work though.

Comment: Thanks David, I can see the logic in the code but it only displays a list of "1". I modified my post with something I've been trying but can't get it right either

Comment: I tried putting the +1 somewhere else and moved adding the array to the end.

Comment: Your if clause always returns true atm, all my months get a +1 when I move the +1 to the $year

Comment: I moved adding it to the array till after it checks. It was always returning true before because it would add the value then check, so it would always be true.

Comment: Just noticed that, it now always returns false haha :p which I don't get really :/

Comment: Got it! I just needed to move the return statement outside of my if. Added the else with a +1 and it did the trick! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. I actually modified my thing a little bit with a different approach, but if that works I would stay with that.